# Not Able to automated while entering text in textfield which is present in UIAlertView for iOS

Tags: ios, testing, automation, monkeytalk

I use the Monkey talk tool for iPhone automation testing and I face problem while I'm entering any text in texfield inside the `UIalertView`. The text is not taking automatic while playing that record which is already entered text in alert view.

If anybody already faced this problem and fixed please help me on this.

Thanks,
Kamal